# Using user input to select a variable to modify?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, attributes

I am trying to modify a variable based on user input. For example if the user wanted to change their strength variable they would type in "strength" and then that variable (tied to a player object so in this example `player.strength`) would be reassigned the new value.

I have attempted using dictionaries to hold the variable name as this is what I've used to call functions/methods as well but after browsing here a bit have realized this will not work due to it being immutable.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
skill_dict = {"Swords": self.swords}
answer = input("Which skill would you like to be proficient in?")
skill_dict[answer] += 10
print(skill_dict[answer])
print(self.swords)
```

The output however shows that this not work with the dictionary value being changed to 10 while the actual variable value remaining unchanged.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why don't use  `class`?

Comment: Related: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict to contain all the player's stats, like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, swords, strength):
        self.skills = {'swords': swords, 'strength': strength}

    def become_proficient(self):
        answer = input("Which skill would you like to be proficient in? ")
        self.skills[answer] += 10
        print(self.skills[answer])
```

Example run:

```
>>> player = Player(5, 6)
>>> player.become_proficient()
Which skill would you like to be proficient in? swords
15
>>> player.become_proficient()
Which skill would you like to be proficient in? strength
16
>>> player.skills
{'swords': 15, 'strength': 16}
```

---

On the other hand, if you **need** to use attributes, you can use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), but this allows the user access to any attributes, which is generally a bad idea.

```
answer = input("Which skill would you like to be proficient in? ")
setattr(self, answer) = getattr(self, answer) + 10
```